# My Maven installation should be working, but is not

Tags: java, maven, installation

I have been troubleshooting my errors for the maven installation on my Mac and must have messed up my PATH variable.  When I do:

```
echo $PATH
```

I get /opt/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin: 
as my return.

My JAVA_HOME is set correctly, but I still get mvn not found.  I did mess around with M2_HOME and M3_HOME, but I'm not sure if that would have any affect.

Comment: Do you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)? If so, it might be easier to use that by `brew install maven`

Answer (score 1):

That message indicates that the command `mvn` can't be found anywhere. Ensure that there is a file `mvn` with execution permissions in `/opt/apache-maven-3.5.4/bin/` directory. If it isn't, you should either update your path or download and extract maven in `/opt/apache-maven-3.5.4/`.

The environment variables `JAVA_HOME`, `M2_HOME` and `M2_HOME` should not have anything to do with this particular error.